# nPOV: Cohomology and derived functors

Tags: cohomology, higher-category-theory, topos-theory, derived-functors

In the [nPOV](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nPOV), cohomology is realized as the connected component of the derived hom space [1]. Namely,

$$H^n(X,Y) = \pi_0 \mathbb{H}(X,B^nY),$$

where $\mathbb{H}$ is an $(\infty,1)$-topos and $B$ is the delooping operation (if well defined). On the other hand, in nPOV, derived functors are simply viewed as $(\infty,1)$-functors between two $(\infty,1)$-categories [2].

While these succinctly express what cohomology and derived functor are, they treat them as two **orthogonal** concepts. This contrasts with the classical point of view, in which both notions are **tied together** in that derived functors are defined to be the cohomology of the sequence induced by resolution of objects.

**Question**: How to explain such difference between both points of view?

#### References

- [1] [nLab: cohomology](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cohomology)
- [2] [nLab: derived functor](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derived+functor)

Comment: For better or for worse, this notion of derived functor is NOT the same (or even morally the same) as the classical notion of derived functor. The classical derived functors are given by the cohomology of the homotopical derived functor. So the answer is: Yes, homotopical derived functors and cohomology are somewhat orthogonal concepts, and you have to combine them to get the classical derived functors.

Comment: How does the homotopical derived functor relates to the nPOV derived functor? Simply by taking $\pi_0(F): \pi_0(C) \to \pi_0(D)$? And how to define the cohomology of the homotopical derived functor in nPOV cohomology (that is, in terms of $\pi_0$ of a derived hom space)?

Comment: By "homotopical derived functor" I mean the same thing as the "nPOV derived functor. The classical derived functors arise in the following situation: Let $D(A)$ and $D(B)$ be the derived category of two abelian categories, and let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a functor which is either left- or right- t-exact. Then there is a homotopical derived functor $Df:D(A)\rightarrow D(B).$ The classical derived functors are obtained by taking the composition $A\rightarrow D(A)\rightarrow D(B)\rightarrow B$, where the last functor is taking $i$th cohomology.

Comment: P.S. I think reading the nLab is a terrible way to actually learn any of these concepts. The nLab is useful as a reference and occasionally useful for gaining a new perspective on things one already knows well, but in this case I think you would be better served by reading any article/book on derived categories.

Comment: @dhy Indeed. The problem is there are many articles and books, and it's not clear to beginners which incooperate the nPOV fully. After getting the high-level idea right, I will try to formulate detailed questions which will require a formal article to answer specifically. // Also, if I understand correctly, a derived category doesn't have full information comparing to an $(infty,1)$ category. If that's the case, any book that deals only derived categories cannot provide a "full-fledged" theory.

Comment: @Student There is no reason to try to implement the nPOV fully. The nPOV is not really a well defined notion and the nLab is not supposed to be a bible. Actually, the nLab is also a wiki: that means it is regularly outated and needs refreshing. In particular when it comes to derived functors, nowadays.

Comment: @Student That said, there is the problem of defining derived functors as Kan extensions (or any other universal property you would see fit) and then the problem to find nice truncation functors to get $\pi_0$ or an analogous construction. As dhy already said it above classical cohomology theories are obtained by truncating derived functors constructed through resolutions.

Comment: @Student I think it is worthwhile to learn old-style derived categories. If you already know how higher categories work then you can mentally translate the theory as you learn it; if you don't, then it will probably be faster to learn it the old way. Incidentally, while it is perhaps true that a derived 1-category on its own does not contain as much information as the corresponding derived $(\infty, 1)$-category, you might like to look up the notion of derivator.

Comment: D.-C. Cisinski, @ZhenLin Thank you for your suggestion. I'm eager to learn from a formal source. Yet it's not an obvious task to choose the correct one. Coming from a department where no one cares $\infty$-category, for a long time I thought the classical derived functor is what we had ultimately. I sensed a vast picture behind it but couldn't formulate. - Anyway, is there a source that's modern enough that deals with this in the most general form? Perhaps Zhen Lin's book on homotopical algebra?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend my notes for learning the subject – they're just scribbles from when I tried to learn the subject back then, and probably in need of reassessment/reorganising/rewriting. I, too, was dissatisfied with the lack of modernised references – but maybe the situation is better now. (I am not up-to-date after leaving academia.) It is good you sense there is a bigger picture. What I wrote in the homological algebra chapter was what I was able to perceive of that picture after absorbing some homotopical culture, but I'm sure experts can give a better exposition.

Comment: The classical examples of cohomology _are_ about higher functors between higher categories: B^nA is an n-groupoid, after all, when A is an abelian group...